# How to only change the page URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know how can I **change** *the page URL* from `example.com/file1.html?i=1` to `example.com/file1.html` in jQuery **without** *changing the page content* or *reloading the page*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will change the URL without redirection or reload to file1.html. If a history push state is not available to use the alternative.

```
if (history.pushState) {
  window.history.pushState("{ Object }", "Title", "file1.html");
} else {
  document.location.href = "file1.html";
}
```

Function

```
function Change(domain, title) {
    let url = domain + 'file1.html';
    window.history.pushState('data', `{$title}`, url);
    document.title = title;
}
```

Comment: I see that this code replaces the page content, and I don't want it to do that

Comment: How is it changing the page content if it does not reload the page?